# Multiple Triggers for a BackgroundTask (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Can a background task have more than one trigger? If yes, do I have to register it for both the triggers?
I intend to use two activation conditions (triggers) in my application for the same BackGroundTask. One for activation of the BackGroundTask by the user and another to activate it by a GeoFence event (which is detected in another background task).

Also after a BackGroundTask has been triggered can I dispose the trigger used to activate it?

Comment: From what I have understood after posting this question, is that Registering a BackGroundTask means running it. (i.e. triggering and registering a background task are the same).
If this is true, I'd like to know if it's possible to register a background task from another background task(in my case the above mentioned GeoFence Background Task).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A background task can have only one trigger. But you can reuse the same code - declare another task in the manifest (and in the code), with another trigger and name but with the same entry point.
For example, I have a background task that s triggered by geofencing, and as fallback mechanism by a time trigger.

Comment: Is your geofence event raised from another background task? 

Also, what is a tome trigger?

Comment: As I understand it, registering a task and triggering it seems to be the same. Is this true?

Comment: Typo, I meant "time" trigger, not "tome". And registering a background task does not trigger it immediately, but makes it available, so that as soon as the trigger fires, it will be executed.

Comment: I don't think you can register background task from another background task, but you should not need it - register all background tasks from the UI and use a combination of triggers, conditions and if needed checking data from a file in the app work folder to make sure the task runs when necessary.